# Autogenerate category based on unique combinations of cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

This seems more confusing than it really is, but I have an Excel sheet that categorizes different combinations of answers.

Each category or tier is based on a unique combination of Yes and No answers between 7 columns.

e.g.:
[image: example sheet]

I'm looking for a way where I can have a blank sheet, and when a user fills in the Yes/No answers, the Tier # will auto-generate based on their responses.

Right now the only possible solution in my limited knowledge is a really long nested IF statement.

Surely a better way exists in Excel? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in Excel 2016 with a helper column and `TEXTJOIN`.

Assuming the list of Tiers is in `Sheet2`, add a column with the following formula in it:

```
=TEXTJOIN(,TRUE,B2:H2)
```

Then in `Sheet1`, add the following formula where you want the tier to appear:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!A$2:A$6,(MATCH(TEXTJOIN(,TRUE,B2:H2),Sheet2!I$2:I$6,0)))
```

`TEXTJOIN` will essentially convert all `y/n` values into a single string. `MATCH` will then look for the matching string on `Sheet2` and `INDEX` will return the corresponding tier.

Comment: There's definitely something useful about converting the line into a single string, but I can't quite get the =INDEX part you suggested to work...it basically just copies over the column of Tier names instead of selecting the appropriate/matching Tier.

Comment: Quite correct: I forgot to make one of the references absolute. See my edited answer